# Hide HTML element from 20:00 to 08:00 GMT

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, settimeout

How can I hide a button from a web page for 12 hours? This is what I have so far:

```
var now = new Date();
var millisTill20 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 20, 0, 0, 0) - now;

if (millisTill20 < 0) {
    millisTill20 += 86400000;
}
console.log('millisTill20 ' + millisTill20);

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#button_online").hide();
}, millisTill20);
```

At 20:00 the script runs, it does hide the element but when I refresh the page the button comes back.

I encountered another issue, if a user comes to my website at 20:01 he can see the button, how can this be fixed?
I understand that this is because I'm using a client-side script but I can't use server-side because I'm using Salesforce.

Comment: Hide the element by default, using CSS, then use JS to check the current time and show it. Re-check the time periodically after that.

Comment: A better solution is to setTimeout every 1 second or 10 seconds or 60 seconds (depending on what resolution you want) and inside that check the time

Comment: Keep in mind that a determined user can manually force the element to show itself at any time. Only server-side code can completely prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will do the job, without using setTimeout().

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();

if(currentHour>19 || currentHour<9) {
    $("#button_online").remove(); // it is better to remove than hide, beacuse someone on client side can still use the button if it is there.
}
```

getHours() function on W3: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp

The above code will remove the button on page load.

But there can be a situation like this:

It's 19:59 and a client loaded the page, the button is not removed. Then it's 20:00 but the button is still there, because the page is loaded on 19:59.

If you want to check this situation too, you can wrap the above code in a function and repeat it periodicly :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkTheTime();
})

function checkTheTime() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();

    if(currentHour>19 || currentHour<9) {
        $("#button_online").remove(); // it is better to remove than hide, beacuse someone on client side can still use the button if it is there.
    }

    setTimeout(checkTheTime, 1000);// period=1 second;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than do all the start/end time math, just get the GMT hour. If it's >= 20, or < 8, hide the element. Otherwise, show it.

```js
function checkOnline() {
  var el = document.getElementById('button_online');

  var hours = (new Date()).getUTCHours();

  if ((hours >= 20) || (hours < 8))
    el.style.display = 'none';
  else
    el.style.display = '';
}

// set correct state on page load
checkOnline();

// re-check once per minute
setInterval( checkOnline, 60000 );
```

```html
<button id=button_online>button</button>
```

Comment: To be more efficient, the function can call itself using *setTimeout* with an interval that is say 95% of the duration until the next change time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think about this a bit differently. This is going to hide the button at a certain time but doesn't handle reloading etc. You need to show or hide it on load. Your script will hide the button if a user has had the page open and not navigating around.

Check if the current time is between those hours and then get rid of the button:

```
var d = new Date();
if (d.getHours() >= 20 && d.getHours() < 8) {
    $("#button_online").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works perfectly fine

```js
var b;
function checkBtn(){
     b=setTimeout(checkTime,1000); // check in every second
}
function checkTime(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    var d = new Date();
    d = d.getHours();
    if(d >= 20 || d<= 8){
      btn.style.display="none";
      clearTimeout(b);
    }
    else{
      btn.style.display="";
      checkBtn();
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="checkBtn();">
<input type="button" id="btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code uses a setInterval to check the time every second. If the current hour is between 8 and 20 it shows the button, otherwise it hides it.

```js
function checkOnlineAvailability() {
  var now = new Date();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  // remove the following line, only present for testing various random hours
  hour = parseInt(Math.random()*24);
  if (hour >= 8 && hour < 20) {
    console.log(hour + 'h is within the available time frame');
    $('#button_online').show();
  } else {
    console.log(hour + 'h is NOT within the available time frame');
    $('#button_online').hide();
  }
}

checkOnlineAvailability();
setInterval(checkOnlineAvailability, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_online">ONLINE</button>
```